# Computing an object 'similarity fingerprint'

Tags: similarity, fingerprinting

### Background

This is a theoretical problem similar to an actual problem I am having.

Imagine I have a database of millions of grades for students with rows looking something like the following:

```
student_id | first_name | last_name | maths_grade | english_grade | physics_grade | chemistry_grade | biology_grade
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  15643    |    John    |   Smith   |     68      |      87       |      54       |      36         |      98  
  13465    |    Alice   |   Jones   |     87      |      54       |      52       |      84         |      23
....
```

### The Problem

I want to find students with the most similar results so I can pair them up as study partners, that way they can both learn from each other, unlike a typical mentor/mentee relationship where only one student learns.

When a given student submits a request for a study partner, I want to find the student in our database that has the most similar grades to the student who made a request.

All subject grades have equal weighting.

### The Required Solution

Since this database has millions of grades, simply looking through the entire database and computing a 'similarity score' for the given student won't work, it would be too slow and wouldn't scale.

Instead, we need to add a `grade_fingerprint` field to the database that contains a 'similarity fingerprint' of the students' grades. We can then index the table on this field and quickly find the two closest students to our given student.

This `grade_fingerpriny` would be similar to a hash code in that it acts as a summary of the table entry, however, two objects with similar properties do not have a similar hash code, which makes them unsuitable.

### Accepted Answers

- The name of a sub-domain of computer science that covers the fingerprinting of objects in a way that allows for easy searching for smiliar objects
- The pseudocode of an algorithm that can compute a 'fingerprint' of an object that can be used to compare object similarity

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Also show the actual database table layout you have. Do you have columns like `maths_grade`, `english_grade` etc or do you have a different layout (keyword: normalization)?

Comment: That's not the issue here. The problem is designing an algorithm to generate a similarity fingerprint for an object. I do not have any attempts at designing such an algorithm since I don't know where to start

Comment: What you are trying to do might not be possible. When student `A` and `B` are "similar" and student `B` and `C` are "similar", that doesn't mean that student `A` and `C` are "similar". However, they might have the same hash value. "Similarity" is not transitive, which might it make difficult to calculate one "similarity" hash value. Please [edit] your question to include example data of several students, indicate which are similar to other students, explain why they are similar and why they are not and what example "hash code" value they have. Add the hash value you want for these students.